# What kind of object type is WP_Query?

Tags: wp-query, shortcode, array

I am getting this error when I try to return the post_title value from my WP_Query:

```
**Fatal error:** Cannot use object of type WP_Query as array
```

Here is the code:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'meta_key' => 'Old ID', 'meta_value' => $atts['oldid'] ) );
return $query['post_title'];
```

How can I show the elements of the post after this query? I am using WP_Query because I am making a shortcode to be used within Posts and Pages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure you understand the logic of `WP_Query`. Rather than explain in words, here's a code example;

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'meta_key' => 'Old ID', 'meta_value' => $atts['oldid'] ) );
if ( $query->have_posts() )
    return $query->posts[0]->post_title;

return '';
```

Check out [the codex on interacting with WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Interacting_with_WP_Query).

**UPDATE**: To use the query as you would normally, i.e. [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop);

```
<?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: One thing—is the return statement supposed to be in { }?

Comment: The `{ }` around the return statement is optional. In PHP, omitting those brackets will apply the `if()` conditional only to the immediate next line.

Comment: Is it possible to return a custom field value using a statement like this? In the codex entry on WP_Query it only talks about custom fields in the context of using them as parameters for the query.

Comment: Or, do I have to rewrite it as, e.g., if 
    ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    Post stuff here. 
    <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata();
so that I can show elements as is done with query_posts?

Comment: $custom_field_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Custom field name', true);

Comment: @supertrue Revised my answer.

Answer (score 1):

the error you get means that you are using an object as an array, if you want to access an object element use `->` and not `[]` so `$query->post_title`

but that wont work either, you need to loop over the post

```
while ($query->have_posts()){
    $query->the_post();
    //here you can use the post data with the $post object
    //$post->post_title
    //$post->content
    //....
}
```